# How do I store each of these sysouts in an if else statment into one solution string

Tags: java, string, if-statement

this project is for a game called Mastermind. I need to create a randomly generated string and store it to a solution so I can later test the solution string to see if the user has entered the correct order.  Ive successfully created the generator to output but I don't know how I am going to get it to the String solution variable. We are not allowed to use arrays for this assignment.

```
    public void makeSolution() {
    int randNum;
    Random randGen = new Random();

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_PEGS; i++) {
        randNum = randGen.nextInt(6);
        if(randNum == 0){
            System.out.print("Y");

        }
        else if(randNum == 1) {
            System.out.print("O");

        }
        else if(randNum == 2) {
            System.out.print("R");

        }
        else if(randNum == 3) {
            System.out.print("B");

        }
        else if(randNum == 4) {
            System.out.print("G");

        }
        else if(randNum == 5) {
            System.out.print("P");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So if I got it right you want to build one string out of what's been printed in the loop and then validate it with an if/else?

Comment: I have another method for validation. This method is only for creating the randomly generated solution string. My output will give me a rando string of each but I don't know how i could get each of these to be put into one string. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah it does. Please check my answer

Comment: Perfect! thank you.

Comment: You can simplify with `String colors = "YORBGP";` and `colors.charAt(randNum);`.

Comment: Matthieu, I will look into trying this as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get rid of all the if/else blocks and just use a loop and access the symbols with the help of a String. This is much more versatile as changing the symbols solely requires changing the string. Also the code gets much shorter and more readable:

```
public String makeSolution() {
    Random randGen = new Random();
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    final String symbols = "YORBGP";

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_PEGS; i++) {
        int index = randGen.nextInt(symbols.length());
        sb.append(symbols.charAt(index));
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I ended up using this method because it does make sense for future versatility.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `StringBuilder` to append the intermediate results and finally you can print the result.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int NUM_OF_PEGS = 5;
        Random randGen = new Random();
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_PEGS; i++) {
            switch (randGen.nextInt(6)) {
            case 0:
                s.append("Y").append("\n");
                break;
            case 1:
                s.append("O").append("\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                s.append("R").append("\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                s.append("B").append("\n");
                break;
            case 4:
                s.append("G").append("\n");
                break;
            case 5:
                s.append("P").append("\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        String solution = s.toString();
        System.out.println(solution);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
O
B
R
O
B
```

**Suggestion:** Instead of `if...else`, use `switch...case` for such cases to structure your code in a better way.

Comment: Whats the point of using two `appends` when you could put both the letter and the newline in the same string literal like `"Y\n"`?

Comment: I've done it purposefully so that if you want to replace the literals e.g. `Y` with a value from some variable/constant/array, you do not have to do `.append("\n")` then.

Answer (score 1):

Use StringBuilder as you build your solution:

```
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

   public void makeSolution() {
    int randNum;
    Random randGen = new Random();

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_PEGS; i++) {
        randNum = randGen.nextInt(6);
        if(randNum == 0){
            System.out.print("Y");
            builder.append("Y");
        }
        else if(randNum == 1) {
            System.out.print("O");
            builder.append("O");
        }
        else if(randNum == 2) {
            System.out.print("R");
            builder.append("R");
        }
        else if(randNum == 3) {
            System.out.print("B");
            builder.append("B");
        }
        else if(randNum == 4) {
            System.out.print("G");
            builder.append("G");
        }
        else if(randNum == 5) {
            System.out.print("P");
            builder.append("P");
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to store it as a string, just call the toString() method on the builder:

```
String solution = builder.toString();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're welcome. If you don't mind, please mark the useful answers with an upvote

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple String concatenation to store your 'solution' string. String concatenation may be slower than StringBuilder but is more readable.

```
public void makeSolution() {
int randNum;
Random randGen = new Random();
String solution = "";

for(int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_PEGS; i++) {
    randNum = randGen.nextInt(6);
    if(randNum == 0){
        solution = solution + "Y";

    }
    else if(randNum == 1) {
        solution = solution + "O";

    }
    else if(randNum == 2) {
        solution = solution + "R";

    }
    else if(randNum == 3) {
        solution = solution + "B";

    }
    else if(randNum == 4) {
        solution = solution + "G";

    }
    else if(randNum == 5) {
        solution = solution + "P";
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should build your string with a `StringBuilder` then once it's built you can validate it after the `for` loop like so:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_PEGS; i++) {
    randNum = randGen.nextInt(6);

    if (randNum == 0){
        sb.append("Y");
    } else if (randNum == 1) {
        sb.append("O");
    } else if (randNum == 2) {
        sb.append("R");
    } else if (randNum == 3) {
        sb.append("B");
    } else if (randNum == 4) {
        sb.append("G");
    } else if (randNum == 5) {
        sb.append("P");
    }
}

// This is your randomly generated solution
String solution = sb.toString();

validateSolution(solution);
```